# How to understand this code sample about define in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#define EVENT_TYPE(DO) DO(EVENT_UNKNOWN), DO(EVENT_SIP), DO(EVENT_MEDIA), \
                     DO(EVENT_APP), DO(EVENT_TIMER), DO(EVENT_BREAK),  \
                     DO(EVENT_STOP), DO(EVENT_MAX)
```

How to understand this code sample about define in C++?

Comment: By looking up what is passed to it (`DO`) and the associated arguments. How could we possibly tell you what it does without that?

Answer (score 2):

Macros are simple substitutions. So whatever you put in EVENT_TYPE's arg get's substituted where you see "DO" in the list of events at the right. E.g., `EVENT_TYPE( GUI )` would be replaced with:

```
GUI(EVENT_UNKNOWN), GUI(EVENT_SIP), GUI(EVENT_MEDIA), \
GUI(EVENT_APP), GUI(EVENT_TIMER), GUI(EVENT_BREAK),   \
GUI(EVENT_STOP), GUI(EVENT_MAX)
```

It's possible that this is intended to be used with other macros so that `GUI` (or whatever is in there) would itself be a macro that would do something like, say, prepend a namespace (so the first element becomes MyNamespace::MyUI::EVENT_UNKNOWN) or concatenates identifier strings (so the first element becomes GUI_EVENT_UNKNOWN).

**Update**:
From your comment:

```
#define STRINGIFY(VAR) #VAR
```

makes a string out of whatever you put in var. Typically that will be a variable name, but it could be an expression. So the preprocessor will transform:

```
int i = 42;
std::cout << STRINGIFY(i)   << " = " << i << '\n' 
          << STRINGIFY(i+1) << " = " << i+1 << '\n';
```

into

```
int i = 42;
std::cout << "i"   << " = " << i << '\n' 
          << "i+1" << " = " << i+1 << '\n';
```

which will print:

```
i = 42
i+1 = 43
```

You can also do symbol concatenation:

```
#define CONCAT(X) prefix_##X##_suffix

int CONCAT(myVar) = 42;
```

will become:

```
int prefix_myVar_suffix = 42;
```

You can also do string concatenation, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: what about #define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR?

Answer (score 1):

It does text substitution to replace `DO` with whatever you give it, such as a function or functor.  The generated code would call the function of functor you pass in place of `DO` for each of `EVENT_UNKNOWN`, ... and returns them as if you placed them a, b, c.

You might use it to create enumerations on a set of events.  For example:

```
// create array of all of EVENT_UKNOWN... as integers
int array[] = { EVENT_TYPE((int)) };

// Create array of strings
class Foo {
public:
   std::string operator()(int val) { ... }
};

Foo f;
std::string strings[] = { EVENT_TYPE(f); }
```

Comment: thanks, what about #define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR

Comment: The # in the macro expansion is known as stringification, or the replacement with the exact string literal.  So, EVENT_TYPE(MAKE_STRINGS) would return the comma separated list of strings of each of "EVENT_UNKNOWN", ...